# Proving $\mathbb{R}^2$ is not separable for this metric?

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, metric-spaces

Let $d_S$ be a metric on $\mathbb{R}^2$ defined as follows $$ d_S(x,y) = \begin{cases} || x- y|| & \text{when} \ x \  \text{and} \ y  \ \text{are linearly dependent} \\ ||x|| + || y || & \text{when}\  x \ \text{and} \ y \ \text{are linearly independent} \end{cases} $$ (This is the French railway metric or Paris metro metric, whatever it is called.) I need to determine if $\mathbb{R}^2$ is separable for this metric.

I think it is not. I wanted to show it the following way. Consider the following subset of $\mathbb{R}^2$:  $$A = \left\{x \in \mathbb{R}^2 \mid d_S(x,0) = 1 \right\}. $$ This is the unit circle centered on the origin. Notice that $A$ is not countable. This is because the interval $[0, 2\pi]$ is not countable. Now let $Q$ be a dense subset of $\mathbb{R}^2$. I want to show that $Q$ is not countable, by showing it contains an uncountable subset. Since $Q$ is dense in $\mathbb{R}^2$, for every $x \in A$ we can find a $q_x \in Q$ such that $d_S(x,q_x) < 1. $ Then now it follows that $$ 1 = d_S(x,0) \leq d_S(x,q_x) + d_S(q_x,0) < 1 + d_S(q_x,0). $$ This means that $d_S(q_x,0) > 0. $ Can I conclude from this that $Q$ contains an uncountable subset, namely $\left\{q_x \mid x \in A\right\}$, and so is uncountable? This would mean $\mathbb{R}^2$ is not separable for $d_S$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All you can conclude from $d_S(q_x,0)>0$ is that $q_x$ is not the point $0$.

You can use the set $A$, but in a completely different way. A separable metric space is second countable, and second countability is a hereditary property: every subspace of a metric space is secound countable. Second countability implies separability, so every subspace of a metric space is separable. Now prove that $A$ is not separable: in fact, it’s an uncountable closed, discrete subset of your space.

Alternatively, show that the open balls $B_{d_S}(x,1)$ for $x\in A$ are pairwise disjoint. If $D$ is a dense set, each of those balls must contain a different point of $D$, and there are uncountably many of those balls.

Comment: I'm trying to show $B_{d_S}(x,1)$ are pairwise disjoint. I assumed the contrary, took an element in the intersection, and trying to derive contradiction now. But I'm not seeing it at the moment.

Comment: @Kamil: For the point of $A$ that is $\langle 1,\theta\rangle$ in polar coordinates, the open ball of radius $1$ is the set of points with polar coordinates $\langle r,\theta\rangle$ for $0<r<2$. That’s an open interval on a ray from the origin. Each $\theta$ gives you a different ray, and the rays are disjoint except at the origin.